# Draw a circle when clicked using quartz

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

I want a circle to be drawn when the user clicks anywhere on the screen. Whats missing/is wrong with this code?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
if (UITouchPhaseBegan)
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 225, 1);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 255, 1);
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(50, 50, 500, 500);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn’t do what you think it does. Have a look at the definition of `UITouchPhaseBegan` in `UITouch.h`:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITouchPhase) {
    UITouchPhaseBegan,             // whenever a finger touches the surface.
    UITouchPhaseMoved,             // whenever a finger moves on the surface.
    UITouchPhaseStationary,        // whenever a finger is touching the surface but hasn't moved since the previous event.
    UITouchPhaseEnded,             // whenever a finger leaves the surface.
    UITouchPhaseCancelled,         // whenever a touch doesn't end but we need to stop tracking (e.g. putting device to face)
};
```

It’s just an enum value, not a reflection of what is going on in your app. I believe that in this case, because it is the first value in the enum, it is probably being set to 0 by the compiler, and is therefore always evaluating to false.

What you probably want to do is to set an ivar like `BOOL _touchHasbegun;`. Then, in `-touchesBegan:withEvent` or your gesture recognizer action, depending on how you’re doing touch handling, set `_touchHasBegun` to YES or NO as appropriate.

When you know your view needs to be updated, call `[self setNeedsDisplay]` (or `[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:someRect]` if you can, for better performance) to trigger the `-drawRect:` method. Then, have your `-drawRect:` method check whether `_touchHasBegun` to determine whether to draw your circle.

Note: You should never call `-drawRect:` yourself. You set the view as dirty, and the OS takes care of drawing it at the right time.

Comment: How do I make the -drawRect method check when _touchHasBegun?

Comment: how do I make -drawRect check when _touchHasBegun?

Comment: Modified my answer to include the use of `-setNeedsDisplay` and `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:`.

Comment: Where should I put the setNeedsDisplay?

Comment: Any time you know the view needs to be updated. Are you using `-touchesBegan:withEvent` and its siblings, or gesture recognizers?

Comment: So, inside `-touchesBegan:withEvent:`, after you have updated any internal state such as `_touchHasBegun = YES`, then call `[self setNeedsDisplay]`, or `[self setNeedsDisplayinRect:someRect]` if you know where you will need to update.

Comment: By the way, you seem to be posting duplicates.